# Is ıt possible to fit a proportional model by hand?

Tags: regression, model, odds

I was asked to solve the question below by hand as a homework. I did it in R, but I think it is impossible to build the model by hand as one needs to conduct numerical analysis to obtain the betas. Am I wrong?

[image]